# Count for next non-weekend (Sat, Sun) day given a startdate and a number of days

Tags: php, function, date, count

So, I have this function:

```
function calculateNextDate($startDate, $days)
{
    $dateTime = new DateTime($startDate);

        while($days) {
            $dateTime->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));    

            if ($dateTime->format('N') < 6) {
                $days--;
            }
        }

    return $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

If I run my function like this:

```
echo calculateNextDate('2012-10-01', '10');
```

It will result in:

```
2012-10-15
```

Which is correct, however I would like it to count the `$startDate` as a counted day, so it will count like this:

```
1. 2012-10-01
2. 2012-10-02
3. 2012-10-03
4. 2012-10-04
5. 2012-10-05
6. 2012-10-08
7. 2012-10-09
8. 2012-10-10
9. 2012-10-11
10. 2012-10-12
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just substract one day first

```
function calculateNextDate($startDate, $days)
{
  $oneDay = new DateInterval('P1D');
  $dateTime = new DateTime($startDate);
  $dateTime->sub($oneDay);

  while($days) {
    $dateTime->add($oneDay);
    if ($dateTime->format('N') < 6) {
      $days--;
    }
  }

  return $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');
}

echo calculateNextDate('2012-10-01', 10);
// results in 2012-10-12
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
function calculateNextDate($startDate, $days)
{
    $dateTime = new DateTime($startDate);
        while($days > 0) {
            $weekend = date('w', strtotime($dateTime->format('Y-m-d')));
            if($weekend != '6' && $weekend != '0'){
                $new_date[] = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');
                $days--;
            }
            $dateTime->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));    
        }
    return $new_date;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r(calculateNextDate('2012-10-11', '10'));
?>
```

The Result would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2012-10-11
    [1] => 2012-10-12
    [2] => 2012-10-15
    [3] => 2012-10-16
    [4] => 2012-10-17
    [5] => 2012-10-18
    [6] => 2012-10-19
    [7] => 2012-10-22
    [8] => 2012-10-23
    [9] => 2012-10-24
)
```

You can echo the date by looping the array.

Answer (score 0):

hmm pretty complicated way to just add a days to start date

I would do this simply like this

```
$resultingDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+$days days", $startDate));
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that it skips weekends.